# cried and begged

Tags: expressions

Below are two options in my grammar questions :

> 1.The newly released 3D Disney movie was supposed to be the best of all time and Joe’s little sister **cried and begged him to take.**
>   2. The newly released 3D Disney movie was supposed to be the best of all time and Joe’s little sister **persistently begged him to take.**

It says second choice is more correct. So, What is wrong in first one ?

Comment: both are missing *her* from the end.

Comment: ok. Lines should end with 'her' ?

Comment: Yes. In this instance *take* requires an object to act on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, *neither* is correct because they are both missing an object. I'm guessing it should end with something like "her to see it." Perhaps you got this from some dialect I'm unfamiliar with where it's OK to leave that implied. So let's pretend that's there on the end.

If you take the first sentence and remove the `and begged` part, you'd get "...Joe's little sister *cried him* to take..", which does indeed make no sense. It should properly be something like "cried at him".

However, I'd argue that the proper way to view this conjunction would be that it joins the phrase "cried" with the phrase "begged him to take...", and is in fact just fine. In fact, its better because it is a much more common construction than "persistently begged".

Comment: thanks to justify more clearly by deconstructing the sentence.

Comment: True about not being able to remove "and begged". But you could say "... cried for him to take her" or "... cried to him to take her". I believe your last paragraph summarizes that issue correctly.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with either one, besides the missing "her" on the end of both. I don't see any grounds for saying that the second is "more correct". (Well, not unless there was additional information in the question about the meaning that the writer intends to convey, and the second better expresses that meaning.)